# Defaulting implementation of private constructor makes it publicly accessible

Tags: c++

Why does the following program compile?

```
struct Foo {
    private:
        Foo() = default;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo b{};
    return 0;
}
```

When the implementation is not defaulted (e.g. `Foo() {}`) it does not compile. The same happens for g++, clang++ and Visual Studio 2019.

I cannot find anything about this in the documentation, any ideas?

Comment: Aggregate initialization (sigh)

Comment: FWIW, This has been fixed in C++20

Comment: Thanks for your replies, my apologies again for not having been able to find this by myself...